# Dynamically allocating memory and assigning of individual array values

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, console, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int main()
{
    int *dizi = new int[3];
    int *ptr = new int;
    *dizi = 1;
    *(dizi + 1) = 2;
    *(dizi + 2) = 3;
    ptr = (dizi + 2);
    delete ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout << *(dizi + i) << endl;
    }
    delete[] dizi;
}
```

I want to return the `dizi[2]` value but I can't, it just crashes how can I do this, can you give me an example?

Comment: `delete ptr` is being called on a memory address that was not returned by `new[]`. That is **undefined behavior**. `ptr` is completely useless in this code and should just be removed completely.

Comment: If you mean that you want to remove an element from the array, the answer is that it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to delete `ptr` is the same as trying to delete `dizi[2]` as you can read in the comment section [`delete` must be used in an address returned by `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176589/dynamicly-returning-memory-from-indivudials-array-values/67176669#comment118740769_67176589). The behavior of your program is undefined.

You also have a memory leak, the memory allocated and assigned to `ptr` will be inaccessible when you reassign `ptr`.

---

If you want to assing the *value* of `dizi + 2` to `ptr` you would need:

```
//...
int *ptr = new int;
*ptr = dizi[2]; // or *(dizi + 2);
std::cout << *ptr; // use it
delete ptr; // delete if after use
//...
```

---

If, on the ther hand, your intention is to assing `dizi + 2` (or `&dizi[2]`) to `ptr`, no memory allocation is needed for `ptr` you can just make the assignment directly:

```
//...
int *ptr = dizi + 2;
std::cout << *ptr;
//...
```

Note that, in this case, after the array deletion, `ptr` becomes dangling, you can no longer use it while it's pointing to `dizi + 2`.

---